# DVI to HDMI vs HDMI to DVI: is there any difference?

Tags: hdmi, cable, dvi

I am looking for a cable to connect a HDMI Laptop to a DVI display. Are all such cables the same or is there a difference which way the conversion goes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it's a male HDMI to a male DVI, you will be fine.

Comment: By the way, you can edit your answer and undelete it too.

Comment: I figured as much, but it was too easy... Seemed like a trap.